# How to set default date and limit it to start date Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker). If I set the default date as today , start date is getting ignored abd let user go back to previous date. I want to restrict going back date from today.

Assuming today is 03/31/2014

```
$('#iBillingDate').datepicker('update',new Date());

$('#iBillingDate').datepicker({
startDate: "03/31/2014",
endDate: 04/30/2014,
orientation: "bottom auto",
daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
todayHighlight: true

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P7BtP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this code your can limit Start & End date, Disable First & Last day of week, and Highlight Todays date. All in single call.

```
$('#iBillingDate').datepicker({
    startDate : '03/31/2014',
    endDate : '04/30/2014',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
    todayHighlight: true
}).datepicker("update", new Date());
```

Fiddle : [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/K82dA/1/)

Comment: I have added JS fiddled, however, it is not working. I am not able to get calendar at all. Not sure what I am missing in jsfiddle. Hope you can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I have tried the above code in my workspace. It is not showing default date in the text feild.

Comment: @user3067524 - sorry for late answer, See my answer updates and Demo, it's working as per your requirement, give your feedback after this...

Comment: Are you sure the demo is working ? I don't see default date in the text box and cannot get calender popup.

Comment: I am using IE9. Could you please confirm if you are using the same ?

Comment: Actually there is a problem with jquery1.10.1. I have changed it to 1.9. and jsfiddle demo is working. Thanks!. Can you please add daysOfWekDisabled "0,6" and todayHighlight is true ?

Comment: Is there anyway to put all these setting in one datePicker() call ?

Comment: @user3067524 - See the answer & demo update, and tell me I understood your desired output or not.